# Why role.Name can get data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I built "Role edit page" but role.Name can't get role data and It Happens  NulReference eror. There is Two role in data but role.Name isn`t get them I research about that But I can't fixed this problem
what do you think about that?

Please Help me I Don't know what am I doing

Controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> RoleEdit(string id)
        {
            var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            var members = new List<User>();
            var nonMembers = new List<User>();

            foreach (var user in _userManager.Users.ToList())
            {
                var list = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name) ?
                            members : nonMembers;
                list.Add(user);
            }
            var model = new RoleDetails()
            {
                Role = role,
                Members = members,
                NonMembers = nonMembers
            };
            return View();
        }
```

RoleEdit View

```
@model RoleDetails
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="RoleEdit">
                <h6 class="bg-info text-white p-1"> Add To @Model.Role.Name</h6>

                <table>
                    @if (Model.NonMembers.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Bütün istfadəçilər rola aid
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var user in Model.NonMembers)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @user.UserName
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="IdsToAdd" value="@user.Id" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </table>
                <hr />

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have to return your view model to the view. Replace this `return View()` with this `return View(model)`.

Comment: Thank you it was fixed it Pleas explain  that me

Comment: Because without specifying `model` in the `View()` call, it doesn't actually send your model data into the View. If you've taken Microsoft's introductory MVC tutorial (available online for free) it should show you these basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        RoleDetails roleDetails = db.RoleDetails.Find(id);
        if (RoleDetails == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(RoleDetails);
        }
```

I don't know what your database name is but you can change it.

If your goal is to have a crud system [try this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application)